# Is there a way to get usage per day/month from Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am planning to get the data and parse it to my own format. Is there anyway to get this?

Comment: See [Azure DevOps Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/what-is-analytics?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get usage per day/month from Azure DevOps?

Organization Settings -> Usage

You can filter to get the usage of the last 24 hours or the last 28 days.

[image]

**Note**: Usage data is only available for the previous 28 days.

Then click the **Save** button to download the `usage.csv` file to the local.

[image]

[image]

**Note**: The maximum number of records (250) was returned.